# Python way of finding if a value exist in a boto.jsonresponse.Element class

Tags: python, boto, amazon-route53

I'm using Boto to get a list of Route53 health checks using this:

```
def list_hc():
    conn = boto.route53.connect_to_region('universal')
    listhc = conn.get_list_health_checks()
    return listhc
```

I get the result as a boto.jsonresponse.Element that looks like this:

```
{u'ListHealthChecksResponse': {u'HealthChecks': [{u'HealthCheckConfig': {u'IPAddress': u'1.1.1.1', u'ResourcePath': u'/', u'RequestInterval': u'30', u'Type': u'HTTP', u'Port': u'80', u'FailureThreshold': u'3'}, u'CallerReference': u'1a311a1c-9da8-424a-9e9d-210ec72738b0', u'HealthCheckVersion': u'1', u'Id': u'1ff1c26f-f0fc-45d2-a008-6dac4dfc3c15'}], u'IsTruncated': u'false', u'MaxItems': u'100'}}
```

I would like to be able to check if an IP is already present as the value for IPAddress and if so, get the value of the Id for it. This list may have several health checks.

At the moment I'm using this ugly way of checking if the IP is there:

```
if pubIp in str(listhc['ListHealthChecksResponse'].values()):
```

But I know there as to be a way to iterate properly over this like it was a dictionary and get key:values, but I can't find the way of doing so on this boto.jsonresponse.Element

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this:

```
ips = [hc['HealthCheckConfig']['IPAddress'] for hc in listhc['ListHealthChecksResponse']['HealthChecks']]
```

The variable `ips` should then contain a list of IP addresses.  Then you could do:

```
if pubIp in ips:
    <do whatever>
```

There are other ways to do it but that would be my preference.

Comment: Thanks, that really did it. I was playing with something like that but didn't get it right.  Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using the '.' on the boto.jsonresponse.Element is the most straightforward. For instance

```
conn.get_list_health_checks().ListHealthChecksResponse.HealthChecks.HealthCheckConfig
```

should make your boto.jsonresponse.Element

```
{u'ListHealthChecksResponse': {u'HealthChecks': [{u'HealthCheckConfig': {u'IPAddress': u'1.1.1.1', u'ResourcePath': u'/', u'RequestInterval': u'30', u'Type': u'HTTP', u'Port': u'80', u'FailureThreshold': u'3'}, u'CallerReference': u'1a311a1c-9da8-424a-9e9d-210ec72738b0', u'HealthCheckVersion': u'1', u'Id': u'1ff1c26f-f0fc-45d2-a008-6dac4dfc3c15'}], u'IsTruncated': u'false', u'MaxItems': u'100'}}
```

into the following list

```
[{u'IPAddress': u'1.1.1.1', 
  u'ResourcePath': u'/', 
  u'RequestInterval': u'30', 
  u'Type': u'HTTP', 
  u'Port': u'80', 
  u'FailureThreshold': u'3'}]
```

Then you can pull out the .IPAddress's

I've done similar things with other boto.jsonresponse.Elements from IAM and EC2 function calls, but I've not actually dealt with Route53 yet. You may not be able to get past .HealthChecks, since there's already a list in there...